# How do I join a select distinct to a select sum?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to join a select disinct statement to a select sum statement.  Here is an example of the data

```
CD  STDATE    ENDDATE   PR
F1  01/02/09  01/04/09  $10
F1  01/02/09  01/04/09  $40
F1  01/02/09  01/04/09  $20
F1  01/02/09  01/04/09  $30
F1  01/22/09  01/26/09  $10
F1  01/22/09  01/26/09  $50
F1  01/22/09  01/26/09  $20
```

My desired output is -

```
F1  01/02/09  01/04/09  $100
F1  01/22/09  01/26/09  $80
```

So far, I have the foll statement, which is incorrect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STDATE, ENDDATE, CD FROM TABLE AS A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(PR) FROM TABLE) AS B 
ON A.STDATE=B.STDATE
```

How can I do that???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for grouping:

```
select
    t.cd,
    t.stdate,
    t.enddate,
    sum(t.pr)
from
    table t
group by
    t.cd,
    t.stdate,
    t.enddate
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Select cd, stdate, enddate, sum(PR)
from Table
group by cd, stdate, enddate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CD,STDATE,ENDDATE,SUM(PR) FROM TABLE GROUP BY CD,STDATE,ENDDATE
```

(missed CD in original answer)

Comment: This doesn't provide the output he's looking for.

Comment: You need the cd field in the select and group by

Answer (score 1):

simple grouping and summing, pick up any SQL programming book

```
SELECT CD, STDATE,ENDDATE,SUM(PR) as SomeSum
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CD, STDATE,ENDDATE
```